# What is the difference between std::condition_variable and std::condition_variable_any?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, condition-variable

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't see any difference between `std::condition_variable` and `std::condition_variable_any`. Why do we need both?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`std::condition_variable` is more specialized, and therefore can be more efficient when you don't need the flexibility of `std::condition_variable_any`.

From N3290 §30.5[thread.condition]/1

> Class `condition_variable` provides
>   a condition variable that can only wait on an object of type `unique_lock<mutex>`, allowing maximum
>   efficiency on some platforms. Class `condition_variable_any` provides a general condition variable that
>    can wait on objects of user-supplied lock types.

Actually, in LLVM's libc++, `condition_variable_any` is implemented using the more specialized `condition_variable` (which uses pthread_cond_t) on a shared_mutex.

Comment: Thanks. It was driving me crazy. I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 30):

The difference is the parameter to the `wait()` functions. All the wait functions in `std::condition_variable` take a lock parameter of type `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&`, whereas the wait functions for `std::condition_variable_any` are all templates, and take a lock parameter of type `Lockable&`, where `Lockable` is a template parameter.

This means that `std::condition_variable_any` can work with user-defined mutex and lock types, and with things like `boost::shared_lock` --- anything that has `lock()` and `unlock()` member functions.

e.g.

```
std::condition_variable_any cond;
boost::shared_mutex m;

void foo() {
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lk(m);
    while(!some_condition()) {
        cond.wait(lk);
    }
}
```

As of C++20, `condition_variable_any` also supports stop tokens for the new jthread class. This means that if you have a condition variable of this type, it will give up the mutex if a stop request is made, without you having to write extra polling code. This feature does not work on `condition_variable` for some technical reasons that were causing "races, deadlocks, and undefined behavior."

```
void testInterruptibleCVWait()
{
    bool ready = false;
    std::mutex readyMutex;
    std::condition_variable_any readyCV;

    std::jthread t([&ready, &readyMutex, &readyCV] (std::stop_token st)
    {
        while (...)
        {

            ...
            {
                std::unique_lock lg{readyMutex};
                readyCV.wait_until(lg, [&ready] {return ready; }, st);
                // also ends wait on stop request for st
            }
            ...
        }
   });
...
} // jthread destructor signals stop request and therefore unblocks the CV wait and ends the started thread
```

See the documentation for details:

[`std::condition_variable` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

[`std::condition_variable_any` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any) and specifically look at the `wait`, `wait_for` and `wait_until` member functions that now honor stop requests on jthreads.

or check out the [latest jthread and stop token C++20 proposal revision](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0660r10.pdf)