# Why isn't std::condition_variable templated by lock type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11

It's useful to have the ability to assert in debug mode, with reasonably small overhead, whether a mutex is locked. Viewing the known options, I've chosen to [implement this using an `std::mutex` subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892934/how-to-assert-if-a-stdmutex-is-locked/30109512#30109512) due to the low overheads.

The interface of the subclass is a superset of that of `std::mutex`, and so most things work well with it. E.g., [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock) is templated to utilize any lock type that has a specific interface.

The problem is with [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), in particular the `wait` members, e.g.:

```
template<class Predicate>
void wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &lock, Predicate pred);
```

As can be seen, the method requires a very specific `unique_lock`/`mutex` combination. Unfortunately, also, the [Liskov principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) doesn't extend for `container<derived>` being converted into `container<base>`.

I don't understand

1. why this is so?

Even if the intent was to enforce the use of `std::unique_lock`, then why couldn't the following be used:

```
template<class Predicate, class Lock=std::mutex>
void wait(std::unique_lock<Lock> &lock, Predicate pred);
```

2. how to reasonably get around this?

**Edit**

As explained by @Lingxi, and further pointed out by @T.C, the absolutely correct and very simple solution here is to use [`condition_variable_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any), which was designed for stuff like this.

Comment: I'm wondering how you will implement the `is_locked` interface based on `std::mutex`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you referring to my link above (in the first paragraph)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758353/whats-the-difference-between-stdcondition-variable-and-stdcondition-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`std::condition_variable_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any). It has a template version of `wait`.

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of its existence. Of course, now I am a bit curious why there are two separate classes, instead of one (possibly with a specialization for instantiating the method with ``std::lock_guard<std::mutex>``),

Comment: `std::condition_variable` may allow some optimization that is not feasible to `std::condition_variable_any`, I guess.