# how to make boost upgrade_to_unique_lock + condition_variable work together?

Tags: c++, boost, condition-variable, readwritelock

I use a std::list to hold some string, one thread writes to the list and some other threads read from it(get the first and erase from the list). Here's the code:

```
std::list<string> list_;

boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::shared_mutex mtx;

int get_size() {
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
    return list_.size();
}

// add a string to the list
// invoked by only one thread
void add_one(const string& p) {
    {
        boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniquelock(lock);

        list_.push_back(p);
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

// get the first string and remove it from the list
// invoked by many threads
string pick_one() {
    string ret;
    {
        boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniquelock(lock);

        if(!list_.size()) { // if empty, wait for notify
            cond.wait(uniquelock, [&]{ return list_.size() > 0; }); // compile error
        } 
        ret = list_.front();
        list_.pop_front();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

There's compile error at line `cond.wait(uniquelock, ...`

What's the correct way of using read/write lock with condition_variable?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this - `upgrade_to_unique_lock` is a RAII helper to obtain exclusive access on the lock for its lifetime.  See docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_to_unique_lock).

> boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock allows for a temporary upgrade of an boost::upgrade_lock to exclusive ownership. When constructed with a reference to an instance of boost::upgrade_lock, if that instance has upgrade ownership on some Lockable object, that ownership is upgraded to exclusive ownership. When the boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock instance is destroyed, the ownership of the Lockable is downgraded back to upgrade ownership.

If you wish to use `shared_mutex` with a Boost condition variable you must use `boost::condition_variable_any` as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). The difference between the two conditional variables (albeit in reference to `std`, not `Boost`) is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758353/whats-the-difference-between-stdcondition-variable-and-stdcondition-variable/8758524).

Comment: Seems `condition_variable_any` should work, but how to create the write-lock without `upgrade_to_unique_lock`?