# Thread safe inter thread queue

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

I was looking for a thread safe queue for inter thread communication using boost but i did not find any thing similar so i came up with my own solution.
1- i used ManualResetEvent [Boost equivalent of ManualResetEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501111/boost-equivalent-of-manualresetevent)

2- the code for the queue

```
MessageQueue::MessageQueue()
{
}
void MessageQueue::Push(void * data)
{
    Locker.lock();
    Queue.push(data);
    Locker.unlock();
    Event.Set();
}
void * MessageQueue::Pop()
{
    void * data = NULL;
    Event.Wait();
    Locker.lock();
    data = Queue.front();
    Queue.pop();
    if(Queue.size() == 0)
    {
      Event.Reset();
    }
    Locker.unlock();
    return data;

 }
 void * MessageQueue::Peek()
 {
    void * data = NULL;
    Locker.lock();
    if(Queue.size() > 0)
    {
      data = Queue.front();
      Queue.pop();
      if(Queue.size() == 0)
         Event.Reset();
    }
    Locker.unlock();
    return data;
 }
 MessageQueue::~MessageQueue(void)
 {
 }
```

it actually work !, but is it the right way to implement queue for inter thread communication ? , is there a better alternative ?

Comment: You haven't shown what `Locker` looks like, but you want to use RAII for locks, so you shouldn't see an `unlock` in most normal code.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use a Boost scoped_lock to handle locking the mutex.

Comment: what is the deference between a simple mutex and "scoped_lock" ?

Comment: A mutex is a mutex. A scoped_lock handles locking and unlocking a mutex -- i.e., when you create a scoped_lock, you pass it a mutex. It locks the mutex in its ctor, and unlocks it in its dtor, so if something throws in-between, you won't accidentally leave a mutex locked (as your code above could).