# Firebreath OpenGl window flickering

Tags: c++, opengl, boost, firebreath

I followed the firebreath opengl [Firebreath Opengl](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/OpenGL+Plugin) tutorial, it works but it start flickering when I resizeing or scrolling the page, so I searched the web for a solution but I did not find any thing except for a small hint

[FireBreath 
  Tips: Drawing on Windows](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-drawing-on-windows/)

it says:

> Whenever a RefreshEvent is received, you must redraw. If you are using a secondary thread to draw, make sure you have some way of passing the message to that thread or you will get flickering.

so that what I tried to do, find a way to pass redraw message to the drawing thread, I used [Boost equivalent of ManualResetEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501111/boost-equivalent-of-manualresetevent) to force the main thread to redraw but nothing happened.

the code I used:

```
bool threadedOpenGLTestPlugin::draw( FB::RefreshEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow* win )
{
   Event.Set(); // Event is Boost equivalent of ManualResetEvent
   //Refresh Events... nothing todo since the opengl is running in it's own thread
   return true;
}
void threadedOpenGLTestPlugin::drawThreaded()
{
   while(true)
   {
      Event.Wait(30);// the event waits for 30 milisec or for event fired by the threadedOpenGLTestPlugin::draw function
      Event.Reset();
      //.......... drawing loop 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I remember someone having this issue and fixing it by handling the [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  You could try that.

Comment: it works thanks a lot, but why dose the getSuppressEraseBackground() return false by default ?

Comment: Huh.  Didn't know that was there; I didn't add that =] I think it's false simply because that is the default behavior.